# What exactly is "the salt of sodom"?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, salt, chulin-tractate, danger, mayim-acharonim

One is obligated to wash one's hands after a meal due to danger of "sodom salt" which is said to cause blindness.

> R. Judah the son of R. Hiyya said: Why did [the Rabbis] say that 
>   it was a bounden duty to wash the  hands  after  the  meal?  Because  of  a  certain salt  of  Sodom  which  makes  the  eyes  blind. Said Abaye.  One  grain  of  this  is  found  in  a  kor  of  ordinary  salt.

Chullin 105. The question is, what exactly is sodom salt that differentiates it from regular salt, yet is somehow mixed in with it? I found a [chabad source](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/564528/jewish/Salt-of-Sodom.htm) which indicates that it refers to caustic chemicals found in natural salt, but it is unsourced and counter intuitive given the premium of natural salts and the apparent lack of danger in the widely used dead sea salts.

Comment: Could you clarify why you associate dead sea salts with salt of Sodom?

Comment: @mevaqesh see sanhedrin 109a where the dead sea is referred to as the "sea of sodom"

Comment: @ShamanSTK It's best to edit relevant information into the question, and not leave it in a comment.

Comment: More concentrate in K+  ?

Comment: ShamanSTK more like the dead sea lies where sodom once did.

Comment: I think @kouty may be on to something. It is possible that in olden days salt produced from the Dead Sea still had quite a bit of potassium in it. Nowadays the process is controlled so that the sodium chloride is pure, but such control would have been difficult then.

Comment: Sodom ! = Sodium